# Configure Canon printer

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon

I have a Canon MG2120.  I want to install drivers for the printer and the scanner. I am on Ubuntu 14.04

I am a complete novice and need to be told what and where to go to install...I have the terminal on side bar but need to know commands, as I said, I need a lot of guidance, don't know much, yet, I'm learning and hopeful; hate windows 7, 8, 8.1. need out.

Answer (score 0):

First try whether it works without additional drivers:

```
system-config-printer
```

and try to `Add`; if it is found there you save a lot of work

If this doesn't work try [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2066330), it is especially about your printer, so this should work

Comment: sysconfig didn't give me anything to go with...

Comment: so try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2066330&p=12278540#post12278540)